# I want to pass stdin to a bash script to an python script called in that bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've a bash script invoking a python script I want to feed the content of `file` via stdin. Calling the bash script like:

```
./script.sh < file
```

And the contents of `script.sh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
pushd /some/python/virtual/environment/working/dir
source venv/bin/activate
python main.py ??????
deactivate
popd
```

I've no idea what to fill in for `??????` to pass the contents of `file` given to the bash script *as stdin* to the python script `main.py`.

Note that `file` can be a substantial text file and using bash's `read` is *not* desirable.

Using stdin when invoking the bash script is a requirement. I'm flexible to pass whatever to `main.py`.

Any ideas out there how to tackle this conundrum?

**addition**

The answer by @cas made it clear to me that I also need to explain in which context I try to use `script.sh`.

I want to use `script.sh` as a *forwarding* script in `~/.forward`, with the contents:

```
|/path/to/script.sh
```

Which postfix does call as `/path/to/script.sh`; the log is clear about that. A simple test using a dressed down version of the python script, like:

```
|/path/to/simple/main.py
```

Demonstrates that postfix does call `main.py` with the content of the mail on the stdin.  But the combination doesn't seem to work.

Comment: are you using postfix's own `local` LDA or something else, like `procmail` or `deliver`?   is there anything in your `~/.bashrc` which might disturb the environment as seen by `main.py` when run from within `script.sh`?   maybe log the environment by running something like `{ typeset -p ; echo } >> "/tmp/forward.log"` inside script.sh.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that your `main.py` script is correctly written to read from stdin **and** that nothing in `venv/bin/activate` reads from stdin(*), `??????` should be "nothing at all".

There are no previous commands in the bash script that will consume stdin before python, so python will just start consuming it.

```
#/bin/bash
pushd /some/python/virtual/environment/working/dir
source venv/bin/activate
python main.py
deactivate
```

Or make `main.py` executable and run it directly as `./main.py`...works the same, either way.

(*) if there was, you probably wouldn't be able to do this at all, without something ugly like capturing all of stdin to a variable and then piping or `<<<` redirecting the variable into first `venv/bin/activate` and then `main.py`.

---

For a very obvious example of what is happening here and why this works, consider the following sh script `kitten.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat
```

It just runs `cat`, which begins reading from stdin and printing its input to stdout.

Comment: awww...the kitty's so cute, it has its own shebang line.

Comment: HI @cas Thanks for the extensive answer.  And, yes it works as it should. I've extended my question to make clear in which context I'm trying to use it and where it doesn't work.  May be then this SE is the wrong forum to ask the question.

Comment: The edit took me more than 6 min ;-)

Comment: If other commands earlier in the script need to consume stdin (future edits to the script, etcetera), _some_ operating systems have pseudo-filenames that can be passed around as placeholders.  Under many flavors of Linux, for example, `/dev/stdin` is a device file (or a symlink to such) that will Do The Right Thing when read from.  The tradeoff, of course, is that portability is limited to the operating systems whose special names you know, e.g., assigning a local variable to the appropriate fake filename and then using the variable as argument to `python main.py`.

Comment: the entire purpose of the OP's script is to set up the environment for python and then pass stdin to main.py, so anything that did that would be breaking it.